# Python join two lists with first index in common

Tags: python, list, zip

I have two python lists with the following data

```
list1 = [[datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3]]
list2 = [[datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 2], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 9]]
```

I have to combine both list with first index ie., `datetime.date` field to be common. Also, if first index does not match for the both, set the value to.

Also if any of the list is blank, set the corresponding position to 0.

The resultant will be

```
list_new = [
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4, 0],
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3, 2],
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 0, 9]
]
```

I tried using `zip` like

```
new_list = [a + [b[1]] for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

But this does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple (non-optimal) one-liner:

```
[[element, dict(list1).get(element, 0), dict(list2).get(element, 0)] for element in set([l[0] for l in list1 + list2])]
```

**Explanation:**

1. Get a set of unique first elements from the list:

```py
>>> s = set([l[0] for l in list1 + list2])
>>> s
set([datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), datetime.date(2019, 12, 16)])
```

2. Convert list of two elements to dict:

```py
>>> d1 = dict(list1)
>>> d1
{datetime.date(2019, 12, 11): 4, datetime.date(2019, 12, 14): 3}
>>> d2 = dict(list2)
>>> d2
{datetime.date(2019, 12, 14): 2, datetime.date(2019, 12, 16): 9}
```

3. Finally, form the resulting list:

```py
>>> [[element] + [d1.get(element, 0)] + [d2.get(element, 0)] for element in s]
[[datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4, 0], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3, 2], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 0, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This merge `list1` and `list2` using [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) (assuming the dates are sorted in each list and in each list there aren't duplicate dates):

```
import datetime
from heapq import merge
from pprint import pprint

list1 = [[datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3]]
list2 = [[datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 2], [datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 9]]

i1 = ((1, v) for v in list1)
i2 = ((2, v) for v in list2)

d = {}
for v in merge(i1, i2, key=lambda k: k[1]):
    d.setdefault(v[1][0], {})[v[0]] = v[1][1]

out = []
for k, v in d.items():
    out.append((k, *[v.get(i, 0) for i in range(1, 3)]))

pprint(out)
```

Print:

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4, 0),
 (datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3, 2),
 (datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 0, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the two list of lists to dicts:

   > dict1 = dict(list1)
   > dict2 = dict(list2)
2. Form the new list as:

   > new_list = [[a,b,dict2.get(a,0)] for a,b in dict1.iteritems()] + [[a,0,b] for a,b in dict2.iteritems() if a not in dict1]

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear about what you're trying to do?

As I understand, you want to make a new nested list, where each item in that list is the combination of items from the input lists which have the same datetime value. What do the other positions indicate?

In your example:

```
list_new = [
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 11), 4, 0],
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 14), 3, 2],
   [datetime.date(2019, 12, 16), 0, 9]
]
```

What do the `4,0   3,2   0,9` correspond to in these entries?

Comment: `4, 0` are the values from two lists respectively, where `4` is from the `list1` and since the `list2` has no value for that date, the default value is set to 0.

Comment: So an assumption you must have here is that in ```list1```, there are no identical dates with different values, right? Otherwise, you must decide how to treat those cases. If I assume the value for a given date will be constant in a list, then you can iterate over both loops separately and update the new list. To be frank, I would recommend you use a different data structure though. Do you need a list? It seems a dictionary would be better to hold the dates as keys.